# Google maps api kml not getting all data

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to do on mouseover instead of on mouse click for google map using google maps api

succeeded in it, but here is the query

it is working fine here: http://code.nebtron.com/o/

however, the popups on mouseover don't have all the data like they have on maps.google.com

obviously kml isn't exporting all of it,

I want the popup cards to be exactly the same as on google map:

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=210314513202687277761.0004add759729f225c40c&hl=en&ie=UTF8&t=m&vpsrc=0&ll=53.758936,-2.358289&spn=6.777111,7.027922&source=embed

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps supports the KML elements mentioned in the link below. Maybe your kml file has some elements not supported.

Moreover:

> The KML parser generally silently ignores XML tags it does not understand.

So do not expect any errors.

[KML in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)

Comment: In addition to checking what KML is supported in Google Maps you should also validate your KML at http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm